# Error resulting from running code in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm running the code in parts in the colab, an error appears in this part. Please tell me what is wrong and if possible how to fix it.

```
model.fit(x, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Error:

```
Epoch 1/2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-3925766564e3> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(x, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks)
 
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False
 
ValueError: in user code:
 
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 240, in __call__
        self.build(y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 182, in build
        self._losses = tf.nest.map_structure(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 353, in _get_loss_object
        loss = losses_mod.get(loss)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2653, in get
        return deserialize(identifier, use_legacy_format=use_legacy_format)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2600, in deserialize
        return legacy_serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/saving/legacy/serialization.py", line 543, in deserialize_keras_object
        raise ValueError(
 
    ValueError: Unknown loss function: 'nse'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

This is the code:

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
# Helper libraries.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

[ ] # daily prices from github
filename = pd.read_csv('/content/SBER_100101_230510 (1) (1).csv')
print(df.shape, df.columns)
df.rename(columns={"<DATE>": "Date", "<TIME>": "Time", "<OPEN>": "Open", "<HIGH>": "High", "<LOW>": "Low", "<CLOSE>": "Close", "<VOL>": "Volume"}, inplace=True)
print (df.shape, df.columns)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d/%m/%y")
print (df.shape, df.columns)


#Убираем сегодняшнюю дату - если скачали сегодня
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today().strftime ('%Y-%m-%d')
last_day = df.at[df.shape [0] -1, 'Date'].strftime ('%Y-%m-%d')
if today == last_day: df = df[:-1]
df

split = 0.85
i_split = int(len(df) * split)
cols = ["Close", "Volume"]
data_train = df.get(cols).values[:i_split]
data_test = df.get(cols).values[i_split:]
len_train = len(data_train)
len_test = len(data_test)
print(len(df), len_train, len_test)

data_train, len_train, data_test, len_test

data_train.shape, data_test.shape

sequence_length = 50; 
input_dim = 2;
batch_size = 32; 
epochs = 2;

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM (100, input_shape=(sequence_length-1, input_dim), return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=False),
  tf.keras.layers. Dropout(.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM (50, input_shape=(sequence_length-1, input_dim), return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers. Dropout(.2),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=False),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])

model.summary()

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, "multi_input_and_output_model.png", show_shapes=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='nse')

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='nse', metrics=['accuracy'])

def normalise_windows (window_data, single_window=False):
  normalised_data = []
  window_data= [window_data] if single_window else window_data
  for window in window_data:
    normalised_window = []
    for col_i in range(window.shape[1]):
      normalised_col= [((float (p) / float(window[0, col_i])) - 1) for p in window[:, col_i]]
      normalised_window.append(normalised_col)
    normalised_window = np.array(normalised_window).T # reshape and transpose array back into original multidimensional format
    normalised_data.append(normalised_window)
  return np.array(normalised_data)

def _next_window(i, seq_len, normalise):
  window=data_train[i:i+seq_len]
  window=normalise_windows (window, single_window=True) [0] if normalise else window
  x = window[:-1]
  y = window[-1, [0]]
  return x, y

def get_train_data(seq_len, normalise):
  data_x = []
  data_y = []
  for i in range(len_train - seq_len + 1):
    x, y = _next_window(i, seq_len, normalise)
    data_x.append(x)
    data_y.append(y)
  return np.array(data_x), np.array(data_y)

x, y = get_train_data(seq_len=sequence_length,normalise=True)

print(x, y, x.shape, y.shape)

def get_train_data2(seq_len, normalise):
  data_windows=[]
  for i in range(len_train - seq_len + 1):
    data_windows.append(data_train[i:i+seq_len])
  data_windows = np.array(data_windows).astype(float)
  data_windows = normalise_windows(data_windows, single_window=False) if normalise else data_windows
  x = data_windows[:, :-1]
  y = data_windows[:, -1, [0]]
  return x,y

x2, y2 = get_train_data2(
  seq_len=sequence_length,
  normalise=True
)

print("train data shapes: ", x.shape, y.shape)
print("train data shapes: ", x2. shape, y2.shape)

import math
steps_per_epoch=math.ceil((len_train - sequence_length) / batch_size)
print(steps_per_epoch)

batch_size=32

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)]

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=2)]

model.fit(x, y, epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, callbacks = callbacks)

model.fit(x,y,epochs=epochs)

def get_test_data()
  data_windows=[]
  for i in range(len_test - seq_len):
    data_windows.append(data_test[i:i+seq_len])
  data_windows = np.array(data_windows).astype(float)
  data_windows = normalise_windows(data_windows, single_window=False) if normalise else data_windows
  x = data_windows[:, :-1]
  y = data_windows[:, -1, [0]]
  return x,y

x_test, y_test = get_test_data(
  seq_len=sequence_length,
  normalise=True
)

print("test data shapes:", x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)

def get_last_data(seq_len, normalise):
  last_data=data_test[seq_len:]
  data_windows=np.array(last_data).astype(float)
  data_windows=normalise_windows(data_windows, single_window=True) if normalise else data_windows
  return data_windows

last_data_2_predict_prices = get_last_data(-(sequence_lenght-1), False)
last_data_2_predict_prices_1st_prise = last_data_2_predict_prices[0][0]
last_data_2_predict = get_last_data(-(sequence_lenght-1), True)
print("*** ", - (-(sequence_lenght-1), last_data_2_predict.size, "***"))

last_data_2_predict

last_data_2_predict_prices

last_data_2_predict_prices_1st_prise

predictions2=model.predict(last_data_2_predict)
print(predictions2, predictions2[0][0])

def de_normalise_predicted(price_1st, _data):
  return (_data+1)*price_1st

predicted_price = de_normalise_predicted(last_data_2_predict_prices_1st_price, predictions2[0][0])
predicted_price
```

Comment: Hi there! Would you mind providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Thanks!

Comment: Can I give you link for my code in colab?

Comment: unfortunately that would go against the SO guidelines `Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included as text in the question itself` - think about it this way, if you post your code here other people who have a similar issue can read the problem you were facing as well as the solution that helped

Comment: added the code at the bottom of the post

Comment: lovely, thanks! would it also be possible to provide some example dataset? Right now I am getting the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/SBER_100101_230510 (1) (1).csv'`

Comment: link to the database from my githab : https://github.com/CloudNE/CloudNE/blob/main/SBER_1%20 (1).csv

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to two typos here:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='nse')

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='nse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

which should mention `mse` (mean squared error) instead of `nse`

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I also had to modify this line here:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y%m%d")  # instead of "%d/%m/%y"
```

Once the model is trained I get an error with the `get_test_data()` function  (`TypeError: get_test_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seq_len'`) but I guess that's your work-in-progress :) Let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Hopefully it will help.

```
def get_test_data(seq_len, normalise):
  data_windows=[]
  for i in range(len_test - seq_len):
    data_windows.append(data_test[i:i+seq_len])
    data_windows = np.array(data_windows).astype(float)
    data_windows = normalise_windows(data_windows, single_window=False) if normalise else data_windows
    x = data_windows[:, :-1]
    y = data_windows[:, -1, [0]]
    return x,y
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).